# Is there a way to gather three dataframes into one dataframe?

Tags: python

I have three data frames and i want to gather them into only one data frame. I tried doing it with pandas package, however the third column does't appear.

For instance:

```
Fil1.txt        
A   B    C
1   2    3
red blue gree

File2.txt       
A    B   C
2    3   5
type dog cat

File3.txt       
F   H   G
7   5   6
red dog blue
```

And when i try to gather them by:

```
all_dataframe=pd.concat([pd_table1, pd_table2, pd_table3], axis=1, sort=False, ignore_index=False)
```

I get this table:

```
Fil1.txt       …    File3.txt       
A   B   C      …    F   H   G
1   2   3      …    7   5   6
red blue gree  …    red dog blue
```

To create this tables i used this code:

```
data_line=open("file1.txt", mode="r")

lines=[]
for line in data_line:
    lines.append(line)
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    # print('{}={}'.format(i+1, line.strip()))
    file1_header=lines[0] 
num_line=1
Dictionary_File1={}
Value_File1= data_type[0:6]
Value_File1_short=[]
i=1
for element in Value_File1:
    type=element.split(',')
    Value_File1_short.append(type[0] + ", " + type[1] + ", " + type[4])
    i += 1
Dictionary_File1[ file1_header]=Value_File1_short
pd_file1=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(Dictionary_File1)
```

The expected result would be: 
[image]

Comment: can you at least provide us your code to see what are you really doing.
for example how you create your pd_table(s).

Comment: yeah, can you provide as well the expected result pls?

Comment: I edited the question to include your topics, many thanks.

Comment: I don't see where your output is different from your expected result. It stacked the 3 dataframes horizontally just like you want. If your issue is with the dots inbetween the columns try expanding your terminal. If there is not enough space to display the whole data, then it will truncate when printing to the terminal.

Comment: I wrote the file to a xlsx and it appeared with all the columns, but now i have another problem, cause the lines are separated by comma, and i wanted them to be separated by tabs. It appears this way:

Comment: Fille1.txt
0 A,B,C
1 1,2,3
2 red,blue,green